# C# + selenium + chrome, Как подгрузить в открытый инстанс(браузер) логин и пароль от установленного прокси?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, прокси

Браузер chrome.
Логин и пароль от прокси сохраняется не в куки, и не в кеш, а в какие то "данные сайтов".
Если куки и кеш можно подгрузить как то на ходу, То эти "данные сайтов" как из текущего браузера сохранить и опять вставить? чтоб вручную каждый раз не вводить.

Прокси без авторизации не подойдут к сожалению.

Comment: Я использую расширение для хрома "Proxy helper". Он может запоминать логин и пароль прокси. Его автоматизирую через селениум.

Comment: Через селен открывать окно настроек расширения нужно сначала обязательно? Или как то командой можно к нему обратиться?

Comment: да после старта хром драйвера сначала заходим в расширение и указываем все параметры.

Если не устраивает такой вариант, то можно переделать расширение - покопаться в исходнике.

Comment: "Сайт mnloefcpaepkpmhaoipjkpikbnkmbnic заблокирован
Расширение заблокировало отправку запроса на сервер."
Через selenium блочится приложение, это решаемо?

Comment: В Chrome headless не пашут расширения оказывается(

Comment: попробуйте это [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46475980/8524602).